# IQueryable serialization (web api)

Tags: serialization, asp.net-web-api, iqueryable

Why isn't this working?:

```
        var surveys = db.Surveys.Where(s => s.Author.UserId == user.UserId);

        return from survey in surveys
               select new
               {
                   surveyId = survey.SurveyId,
                   title = survey.Title
               };
```

And this, with a minor change, is?:

```
        var surveys = db.Surveys.Where(s => s.Author == user);

        return from survey in surveys
               select new
               {
                   surveyId = survey.SurveyId,
                   title = survey.Title
               };
```

It throws a serialization error

```
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 
'application/xml; charset=utf-8'.  (...)
```

I'm fine with solving it that way, but I have the same error here (below), and can't solve it the same way:

```
var surveys = db.Surveys.Where(s => s.AnswerableBy(user));
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue recently, in my case the problem was that I had **circular references** created by the Entity Framework - Model First (Company -> Employee -> Company).

I resolved it by simply creating a view model object that had only the properties I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As per the section 'Handling Circular Object References' [here on the Microsoft ASP.NET Web API website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling_circular_object_references), add the following lines of code to the Register method of your WebAPIConfig.cs file (should be in the App_Start folder of your project).

```
        var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

There are separate instructions on that page for dealing with XML parsing.

Comment: then, my response to webapi, was in json, but, is better for me

Comment: Perhaps some more explanation how and why this solves the problem would be appropriate. It doesn't seem obvious to me.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are seeing is a general exception, which can be caused by any number of factors. Check the `InnerException` property of the serialization exception to find out what exactly caused the serialization to fail.

Comment: "Type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[MySln.Models.Survey,<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Int32,System.String]]' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types."  But I don't want to serialize a "Survey", but a subset of properties of this (thats why i'm using dynamic)

Comment: Edit: Ok, thanks, the problem was that IsAnswerable(·) couldn' be translated into a LINQ query. Now I really don't know how to solve this without modifying the architecture, damn' it.

Comment: A common trick is to add a `ToList` call to the call chain. This forces LINQ to execute the query and pull all data in memory. For example: `var surveys = db.Surveys.ToList().Where(s => s.AnswerableBy(user));`

Comment: I must add that shifting query execution from LINQ-to-SQL to LINQ-to-Objects has some obvious drawbacks. In most scenarios you will lose performance as SQL is better equipped to manage queries. If your `Surveys` table is going to contain millions of rows, then pulling all that data in memory before applying a filter is an inefficient solution.

Comment: whooaa that helped! Thank you Martin Devillers. I am indeed going to have millions of rows, but for now I'm fine with a nice clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an anonymous object. Make it strongly typed and the serialization will work.

Comment: Looks like you could even do a Dictionary<int, string> if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

At the end this has to do with Linq to Entities vs Linq to Objects.

Some LINQ queries can not be translated into SQL (like using a method: someCollection.Where(p => p.SomeMethod() == ...)). So they must be translated to memory first (someCollection.ToList().Where...)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. In my case the error was caused by the **relation between tables created in my Dbml file**. Once I removed the relation from the DBML file, it worked. I think Database relations can't be serialized.